# How to replace string that includes square brackets with regex and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace a string coming in from JSON that I need to find and replace.

I need to find all instances of the text "[REPLACE THIS]" with the brackets (but not the quotes) and replace it with a string of my choosing. But I want to remove the brackets from the finished result. How can I remove these brackets?

Here is my code:

```js
var text = "[REPLACE THIS]";

var newText = text.replace(/REPLACE THIS/g, "Replacement Text");

console.log(newText);
```

Comment: smth like this?: `/\[REPLACE THIS\]/g`

Comment: I think the regex is ```/\[REPLACE THIS]/g``` that you need. If I remember correctly it will find all instances of that string and replace them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the brackets using `\`

```js
var text = "[REPLACE THIS]";

var newText = text.replace(/\[REPLACE THIS\]/g, "Replacement Text");

console.log(newText);
```